# Final boolean is changing value

Tags: android, boolean, final

I have a class variable that is final and is set in the constructor. When I check the value of it in the constructor for the abstract class and the subclass it's the correct value. But when I check it later in a method it's always false. Here's my code.

```
abstract class AbstractArticleObject extends StructureObject {

    final boolean firstArticle;

    AbstractArticleObject(Element element, boolean firstArticle) {
        super(element);

        this.firstArticle = firstArticle;

        ...
    }

}

class ArticleObject extends AbstractArticleObject {

    ArticleObject(Element element, boolean firstArticle) {
        super(element, firstArticle);

        // In this method, firstArticle is whatever was passed in, which is sometimes true.
        Log.v(title, String.format(String.valueOf(this.firstArticle));
    }

    @Override
    StructureState getState() {
        // In this method, firstArticle is always false.
        Log.v(title, String.format(String.valueOf(firstArticle));

        if (...) {
            ...
        } else if (...) {
            if (firstArticle) {
                return StructureState.CAN_OPEN;
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }

        return StructureState.NOT_SET;
    }
}
```

If I'm setting the value in the constructor, and the value is final, why is it returning false even when it was set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is `getState()` called from?

It is possible for `final` variables to "change" if you access them before they're ever initialized. Consider the following tiny program:

```
public class Test {

    private final boolean value;

    public Test() {
        doSomething();
        this.value = true;
        doSomething();
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

The output of this program will be

```
false
true
```

So, if your `getState()` method is called from e.g. the constructor of `StructureObject`, then it will be called before the `AbstractArticleObject` constructor initializes `firstArticle`, and it will be `false`.

Comment: I doubt `getState()` is called before the class is instantiated. According to OP's code, the value is set in the constructor.

Comment: The value is set after a `super()` call, and the method in question is an `@Override` not declared in his posted code, with a name prefixed with `Structure` when the super constructor is for `StructureObject`. I think it's highly likely it's called before the field is initialized.

Comment: But `ArticleObject` extends `AbstractArticleObject`, and `super()` is called right away in its constructor. Doesn't the constructor need to complete before the thread can continue?

Comment: @Ben P. getState() is called in the StructureObject constructor. I will have to check tomorrow once I'm in the office, but it sounds like that's what I did. Does boolean default to false instead of null?

Comment: @CodyHarness primitives all have default values; boolean will be false, int will be 0, etc. `null` is only the default value for object references.